# Invalid pointer in visual studio when running project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In visual studio 2013 when I run my project it build but don't lunch and throw this error 
"Invalid pointer"

Comment: What language and show some code as you have given zero information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual Studio 2013 I canceled my update and it canceled without any problem but when I want to run my project it doesn't run,I had to complete my update to solve this problem.
Thanks All